# Find $a,b$ such that $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ to be in an arithmetic progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x^4-8x^3+ax^2+8x+b=0$ with $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\in\mathbb{C}$.

We need to find $a,b$ such that $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ to be in an arithmetic progression.

Here is all my steps:

- Observe that for $a=14\Rightarrow x_1+x_4=x_2+x_3=4$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{4} x_k=8\Rightarrow z=2$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{1\leq k<i\leq 4} x_k x_i=x_1x_4+x_2x_3=-2$$

- Therefore we obtain another relation: $x_1x_4+x_2x_3=-1$

$\Rightarrow 2z^2-10r^2=-2\Rightarrow r^2=1\Rightarrow r=\pm 1$

$$\prod_{k=1}^{4} x_k=-15=b$$

> Is something wrong in my solution ?

Comment: By "AP" do you mean Arithmetic Progression?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let the roots be $A\pm D,A\pm3D$

$\implies A-3D+A-D+A+D+A+3D=8\iff A=2$

and $-8=\sum A(A-D)(A-3D)=?  $

Comment: @Lucas, As it immediately gives $A=2$ . Had it been odd number terms, we could choose $\cdots,a-2d,a-d,a,a+d,a+2d\cdots$

Comment: @Lucas, What can you derive if you choose $a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d?$

Comment: @Lucas, May I know the reason behind deleting a nice question that's still awaiting good answers?